# Django Rest Framework | Put method not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am creating a rest api using DRF the get and post method work perfectly but the put method doesnt update the request

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response

from BarakaSalesSystemApp.models import Farmer
from BarakaSalesSystemApp.serializers import FarmerSerializer

def list(self, request):
    farmer = Farmer.objects.all()
    serializer = FarmerSerializer(farmer, many=True, context={"request": request})
    response_dict = {"error": False, "message": "All Farmers List Data", "data": serializer.data}

    return Response(response_dict)

def create(self, request):
    try:
        serializer = FarmerSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Farmers Data Saved Successfully"}
    except:
        dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "Error During Saving Farmers Data"}

    return Response(dict_response)

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    try:
        queryset = Farmer.objects.all()
        farmer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = FarmerSerializer(farmer, data=request.data, context={"request": request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Successfully Updated Farmer Data"}
    except:
        dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "Error During Updating Farmer Data"}

    return Response(dict_response)


farmer_list = FarmerViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"})
farmer_create = FarmerViewSet.as_view({"post": "create"})
farmer_update = FarmerViewSet.as_view({"put": "update"})
```

and this is my serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from BarakaSalesSystemApp.models import Farmer, Customer, Order, Bill, Employee, Delivery
class FarmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Farmer
    fields = ["name", "address", "contact", "in_stock"]
```

When requesting for the put request on postman it gives the error message and not updating

Comment: Please add the full traceback from your error to the question. Does this help https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates?

Comment: the restsponse i getfrom postmna when callingthe put request is 
{"error": "true", "message": "Error During Updating Farmer Data"}

Comment: The docs I linked suggest passing `partial=True` to the serializer in your update method. If that doesn't help then adding the full traceback to your question will give more clarity

Comment: I figured out the probem I had'nt declared the id field in my serializer added it and it works perfectly fields = ["id", "name", "address", "contact", "in_stock"]

Comment: change this part serializer = FarmerSerializer(data=request.data), It was better to use ModelViewSet.

Comment: There is no reason to define 'custom' methods for create, list, and update If their implementation are just equals as Implemented in Django. I suggest your simple use a Class Based View using DjangoModelMixin 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview